# How to forward arguments after processing the arguments in a variadic function

Tags: c++

I want to implement a function `wrapper1` and `wrapper2` in C++.

Calling `wrapper1(f, g, x1, x2, ..., xn)` is just like calling `f(g(x1), g(x2), ..., g(xn))`.

Calling `wrapper2(f, g, h, x1, x2, ..., xn)` is just like calling `f(g(x1), g(x2), ..., g(xn), h(x1), h(x2), ..., h(xn))`.

(Of course, if g(x) and h(x) is defined as x, we can use `template` to forward the arguments).

(I consider `wrapper1` and `wrapper2` are two different forwards because the target function has different number of arguments).

How could I implement these two wrappers in C++? Suppose that I always know the function signatures when both compiling and executing.

---

Here is an example about how I would use these wrapper function.

I want to design a program supervisor `A`, and it monitors a program `B`. Each time `B`
calls a function `f`, `A` will check all the arguments passed to `f`, and it might alter the arguments.

The process is started with a command: `./A --target-program ./B --config-file config.json`

Every time `B` calls `foo("Hello", "World")`, before actually execute `foo`, the control flow will be delivered to `A`.

`A` might alter the argument, e.g., adding a prefix to the string.

`A` can call `wrapper(foo, add_prefix, "Hello", "World")`, where `add_prefix(x) = "Bob says:" + x`.

So every time `B` calls something with strings, there will be a prefix `Bob says:` to the strings.

`A` reads the signature of the monitored function (`foo(string x, string y)` in this example)from the config file `config.json`.

Comment: Your requirements would be a lot clearer if you showed an example of how you would use these wrapper functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the answer, you basically need to use `std::forward`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename F, typename G, typename... X>
void wrapper1(F f, G g, X&&... x)
{
    f(std::forward<X>(g(x))...);
}

template <typename F, typename G, typename H, typename... X>
void wrapper2(F f, G g, H h, X&&... x)
{
    f(std::forward<X>(g(x))..., std::forward<X>(h(x))...);
}

int g(int x)
{
    return x + 1;
}

int h(int x)
{
    return x + 2;
}

void f1(int a, int b, int c)
{
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << std::endl;
}

void f2(int a1, int b1, int c1, int a2, int b2, int c2)
{
    std::cout << a1 << ", " << b1 << ", " << c1
              << a2 << ", " << b2 << ", " << c2 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    wrapper1(f1, g, 1, 2, 3);
    wrapper2(f2, g, h, 1, 2, 3);
}
```

The output of this is:

```
2, 3, 4
2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: I would recommend _not_ using `std::forward` in `wrapper2`.  It's fine for this trivial example, but if you're dealing with something more complex than `int`s `g` could move from one of the arguments and leave no value for `h` to consume.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know `forward` can be used in this way before. Is it possible to do something like this: `wrapper3(f, g, x1, x2, x3, x3, ...) = f(g(x1, x2), g(x3, x4), ....)`?

Comment: Also this example won't even compile. `std::forward<X>(g(x))` should be `g(std::forward<X>(x))`.